# Covering subset with large probability

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability

Let $c>0$, $0<\lambda<1$, and let $k\in \mathbb{N}$ be sufficiently large. Let $X$ be a uniformly random subset of $\{1,\cdots,N\}$. Denote by $[N]^x$ the collection of $[x]$-element subset of $\{1,\cdots,N\}$.

Prove that: for any sufficiently large $N\in\mathbb{N}$ (depending on $c$), any function 
$f:[N]^{\frac{1}{2}N-c\sqrt{N}}\rightarrow k$, there exists a subset $K$ of $\{1,\cdots,k\}$ with $|K|/k\leq \lambda$ such that $\mathbb{P}(\exists F\in f^{-1}(K)[F\subseteq X]\ \big|\ |X|>\frac{1}{2}N-c\sqrt{N})\geq 1-\lambda$.

Comment: What's the use of the function $f$?

Comment: It's corrected. Sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 2):

It is true. Let $k=\binom{N}{N/2-c\sqrt N}$ and let $K$ be a randomly* selected subset of $k$ of size $k\lambda$. Then conditionally on $|X|>N/2-c\sqrt N$, the difference $|X|-(N/2-c\sqrt N)$ is unbounded as $N\to\infty$, so $X$ has an unbounded number of subsets of size $N/2-c\sqrt N$. So since $f^{-1}(K)$ contains a bounded-below (by $\lambda$) fraction of all such subsets, and *a $\lambda$ fraction  of an unbounded amount is another unbounded amount*, almost surely (in the limit as $N\to\infty$) $X$ contains one of the sets in $f^{-1}(K)$.

*We take the probability of $K$ being chosen to be proportional to the cardinality of $f^{-1}(K)$.

Comment: Ops. There is a mistake in the statement~ The probability is conditional on: the size of X is larger than N/2-c\sqrt{N}. The question is related to an open question in your paper whether there is a set covers REC but not RE.

Comment: No worries I answered the new version now

Comment: But $f$ is a given function. In your answer it seems you choose f to be a one-one function.

Comment: @JiayiLiu my answer is motivated by the one-one case but the general case is handled by: "We take the probability of $K$ being chosen to be proportional to the cardinality of $f^{-1}(K)$ "

Comment: Right. I need to rethink about the question I'm asking. I actually want $N$ to be very large and $k$ fixed (but yet sufficiently large).